# Sitecore Select Media return empty in Experience Editor - Multisite SXA

Tags: sitecore-client, content-search, experience-editor, media-library

We have recently upgraded the Site from `v9.2 to 10.2`. We have maintained multisite with SXA. In the old Site, we used Azure Search and now converted it into Solr search. After integrating all the things in the experience editor `select media` always return null. But if we click the tree structure on the left side it returns the result. Not getting any result if we click on List View

**Note**: I have to rebuilded all the Sitecore index and that is successfully indexed.

[image]

Comment: If I remember correctly, by default this view shows only media items uploaded in last 8 days. Can you check if you upload any new item, will it appear in this view?

Comment: I have clicked all the options from the left side but no result return

Comment: And if you upload any new one, is it displayed?

Comment: @MarekMusielak I have upload the new image but it is not displayed

Comment: Issues on this dialog are generally related to indexing. If you are able to successfully rebuild the indexes I would try querying for the images directly on Solr to make sure Solr is actually returning the results.

Comment: image result is getting in search query